# Create a list from a txt file with all italian words, python

Tags: python, list, words

I downloaded from here ( https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=128318&package_id=141110 ) a dictionary with all the italian words. I wanted to add them to a list so I could use randint(0, list.count()) to use a random italian word as a string. 
The little program is basically "Guess the word".
I used this guide: [Creating a list of every word from a text file without spaces, punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135967/creating-a-list-of-every-word-from-a-text-file-without-spaces-punctuation) to see what I could do to achieve this, but I received ascii code errors. Then I tried to replace the odd characters (‡ËÈÏÚ) with their effective characters (àèèìù) and I removed the first line of the thesaurus.txt file, but I still get the same ascii error.
Thank you in advance for your help, I'm a newbie in Python.
Oh, and here's the code, so that you can recreate the ascii error (you can download the .txt file from the link above).

```
import re
from random import *
file = open('thesaurus.txt', 'r')
# .lower() returns a version with all upper case characters replaced with lower case characters.
text = file.read().lower()
file.close()
# replaces anything that is not a lowercase letter, a space, or an apostrophe with a space:
text = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text)
words = list(text.split())

word = random.choice(words)

wordlist = list(word)

guess = []
prove = []

for l in range(len(word)):
    guess.append("_")
attempts_remaining = 6
print (guess)
print("You have", attempts_remaining, "attempts")
guessed = 0
while guessed < len(word) and attempts_remaining != 0:
    if attempts_remaining != 0:
        guessed_this_time = 0
        prova = input("Write a letter: ")
        prove.append(prova)

        if prove.count(prova) > 1:
            prova = input("You've already tried this letter! Try with another: ")


        for l in range(len(word)):


            if wordlist[l] == prova:

                guess[l] = wordlist [l]
                guessed += 1
                guessed_this_time += 1    


            else:
                pass
        if guessed_this_time == 0:
            attempts_remaining -= 1
            print(attempts_remaining, "attempts remaining")
        elif guessed == len(word):
            print("You guessed it!")
        print(guess)
    if attempts_remaining == 0:
        print("You lost, the word was", word)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/Impiccato/impiccato.py", line 5, in <module>
    text = file.read().lower()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 2170: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Edit: I "solved" moving all the txt content into the .py and calling it this way:

```
text = """
here's all the list (the whole thing is 19414Ln LOL)
... """
words = \
re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text).split() # Stores the secret words in a list
```

This way commas are replaced by spaces.

Comment: I can see one obvious error: You can't use commas to slice the wordlist. I think you want `random.choice(wordlist)`

Comment: And what exactly are the errors you are getting?

Comment: The file is an oxt not a txt?

Comment: the link was wrong, this is the correct link to download https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=128318&package_id=141110
@PadraicCunningham

Comment: @Maltysen wordlist is not actually the list of all the words (the dictionary), but a list that contains the characters of the word ( in this explicit case is "canestro" an italian word). Maybe this can help you to help me :D

Comment: sorry, didn't mean `wordlist` I meant the `words` variable.

Comment: @Maltysen so I should replace what with random.choice(wordlist)?
By the way, the link to download the dictionary is now correct so you can have a look. The words are separated by commas.

Comment: `words[0, randint(0, words.count())]` The part in the comment. and with `random.choice(words)`, you were right about that.

Comment: But the ascii error is likely something completely unrelated.

Comment: @Maltysen Yeah, thanks, random.choice is much cleaner. Could you try it, so that we can check the ascii error ? I can upload the edited version of thesaurus.txt if you want.
(should i move this discussion to chat?)

Answer (score 0):

It was the encoding. I don't know what that website had it set as, but its not what you want. Just open it up in you favorite editor and set the encoding to `UTF-8`. It still won't work, because of another bug: `.count()` does *not* give you the amount of items. You want `len(words)`.

Comment: do I have to pick the original file or the one I edited (removing the first line and using search and replace to replace the other characters) ?

Comment: ok thanks. I updated the code above completely removing the .count(), but i'm not sure why shouldn't it give you the amount of items. I also want to not add the words listed that contain an apostrophe, such as "we're", because that would be impossible to guess :D
I'll update the question with the specific error, since it appears that saving to unicode-8 does not make any difference.

Comment: @PierCarloCadoppi really, that fixed it for me. And also, make sure that it is  `UTF-8`. What do u mean by `unicode-8`?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ymvo2xwu7652ne/Screenshot%202015-06-20%2001.55.20.png?dl=0